# Keeping Class Component methods pure by instead passing props or state as arguments

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

It's typical to access props/state from within Class Component methods as in `bar()` however, it's much nicer to unit test a more pure equivalent as in `foo()` as you don't have to repeatedly mock external state.

```
foo(state, props) {
    // do something with state or props passed as argument

}

bar() {
    // do something with this.state or this.props directly
}
```

However something about having state/props available throughout a Class, but passing state/props as arguments in all methods which could be pure feels antithetical to the Component state/props typical usage patterns.

Is this the typical way of refactoring Class Component methods for easier unit testing, or am I missing some React functionality which does this behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to test. For example if you'd test your components the way a user would interact with them, you'd write your assertions in a way that test if the rendered output is correct and if it correctly changes based on various interactions with it (button click, etc). In that case you wouldn't need to concern yourself with such implementation details as which props/state a component has at a certain point of time.

Comment: I want to test my Class Component methods in isolation. Typical unit testing stuff. What makes that easier is keeping functions pure whenever possible so you avoid having to mock/simulate external states. My point was that state and props are integral to components and their methods and passing them as arguments, whilst making unit testing cleaner, kind of conflicts with having state and props accessible throughout the class.